# Cannot be referenced from static context error

Tags: java

I have two classes inside Main class. I want to instantiate both objects of that classes in static main method. But i'm getting "cannot be referenced from static context error". Where i'm wrong?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent p = new Parent();
    }

    public class Parent {
        String x = "Parent";
        public void print() {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }

    public class Child extends Parent {
        String x = "Child";
        public void print() {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you put all the classes into one file you have just created 2 inner classes. You probably did not intend to do that and rather want to have 2 normal classes. Therefor you should put each class into its own file.

Comment: Or make them **static** inner classes with `public static class Parent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parent and Child classes depend on an instance of Main because they are inner classes.

If you want to create a Parent or Child instance, you can do two things.

- Create an instance of Main and then use this reference to create Parent or Child.

```
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Main m = new Main();
            Main.Parent p = m.new Parent();
        }

        public class Parent {
            String x = "Parent";
            public void print() {
                System.out.println(x);
            }
        }

        public class Child extends Parent {
            String x = "Child";
            public void print() {
                System.out.println(x);
            }
        }    
    }
```

- Change class declaration of Parent and Child and add static

```
    public class Main {    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Parent p = new Parent();
        }

        public static class Parent {
            String x = "Parent";
            public void print() {
                System.out.println(x);
            }
        }

        public static class Child extends Parent {
            String x = "Child";
            public void print() {
                System.out.println(x);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks. If I choose 1-st option (create instance of main and then create Parent/Child), how can I do it? 
Main main = new Main(). And then?

Comment: With `Main m = new Main();
    Main.Parent p = new m.Parent();`

Comment: I try to do:
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
        Main.Parent pr = new m.Parent();
    }
But it gives me an error: package "m" does not exist.

Comment: Could you post the entire code ? With the class declaration.

Comment: package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Main m = new Main();
        Main.Parent pr = new m.Parent();

    }

    public class Parent {
        String x = "Parent";
        public void print() {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }

    public class Child extends Parent {
        String x = "Child";
        public void print() {
            System.out.println(x);
            System.out.println(super.x);
        }
    }

}

Comment: Finally figured it out. 
Now it works:        
Main m = new Main();
Main.Parent pr =  m.new Parent();
Main.Parent ch =  m.new Child();
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I misstyped it. Glad it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can either take the classes out of the main method but its a very **messy** way and is not suggested at all.

```
public class SOTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent p = new Parent();
    }
}
class Parent {
    String x = "Parent";
    public void print() {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    String x = "Child";
    public void print() {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Or one of the best way is to make the Parent & Child class as non static inner class as below

```
public class SOTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SOTest soTest = new SOTest();
        Parent p = soTest.new Parent(); //Example of non static inner class
    }

    class Parent {
        String x = "Parent";
        public void print() {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }

    class Child extends Parent {
        String x = "Child";
        public void print() {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Or possibly static inner class (depends upon your requirement)

```
public class SOTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent p = new SOTest.Parent(); //Example of static inner class
    }

    static class Parent {
        String x = "Parent";
        public void print() {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }

    static class Child extends Parent {
        String x = "Child";
        public void print() {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
}
```